# Upgrade from IBM WSED 5.1.2 to IBM RAD 7.5

Tags: java, websphere, development-environment, ibm-rad

Our group currently uses Websphere Studio Enterprise Developer V. 5.1.2.  This is, for various reasons, no longer sufficient for our application, so we are upgrading to the latest version that we have available, IBM Rational Application Developer 7.5.

So far, we have hit a few...snags.  In trying to import an old EAR file, over 1,000 application errors were reported, leading us to suspect this may not be the optimal way to migrate our software.  In addition, the Help Documentation implies we will have to upgrade our server to 6.0 before we can even *consider* an upgrade to 7.5.

We would like to make this transition as seamlessly as possible.  I have heard that there are migration tools out there to do so, but I'm not sure how to use them, or how wise it is to use them on highly sensitive applications.  And we are not at all sure how to perform a server upgrade from 5.0 to 7.0.

What can we do to make this upgrade as quick and seamless as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking WAS servers have a level of backward compatibility, we use this in our place, running ears originally targetting WAS 5 but now deployed on WAS 6 (with no code changes).

i.e. your old .ear may be able to be deployed and run on the later version of the server, so this may be an a low hanging fruit option, but would mean you would still use your old IDE to make changes.

Remember you are probably shifting JDK version as well as WAS version, so any language changes - reserved words or deprecation of class/methods may impact you (all depends which language and WAS features your app/code uses).

The IBM often offer an uplift tool "Migration Tool" to uplift versions,

See

- [Knowledge Collection: Migrating to (or from) WebSphere Application Server V7.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013842)
- [Redbook - WebSphere Application Server V7 Migration Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4635.html?Open)
- [IBM WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/)